# How we can redirect to plugin controller Action From Nop.web View in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have created one custom payment plugin and I want  redirect to that Plugin Controller
action on submit button of Nop.web View

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me more detail i can't undestand your problem

Comment: Hi Vap,I have created a payment Plugin and I want to redirect in action of that payment Plugin controller on clicking of submit button of E_payment.cshtml which is in the namespace Nop.Web.View.Common. I am not getting the way to redirect there

Answer (score 0):

In the class that implements the IPlugin interface, a couple routes will be defined.  Eg.

```
public void GetConfigurationRoute(out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    actionName = "Configure";
    controllerName = "SomePlugin";
    routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary { { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Payments.SomePlugin.Controllers" }, { "area", null } };
}
```

You can redirect to these actions by using the following.

```
public ActionResult RedirectToPlugin()
{
    return RedirectToAction("ConfigureMethod", "Payment", new { area = "Admin", systemName = "Payments.SomePlugin" });
}
```